# What mistake am I making in the function definition(C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I have this code thats supposed to do this

```
// REQUIRES: n >= 1. Elements a[0] ... a[n-1] exist. 
// PROMISES
//   If n == 1, returns 1.
//   Returns 1 if all of a[0] <= a[1] ... a[n-2] <= a[n-1] are true.
//   Otherwise, returns 0.


#include <assert.h>

#include "array-utils4F.h"

#define UNIT_TESTS 1
int is_sorted(const int *a, int n)
{
  assert (n >= 1);

  if (n == 1)
    return 1;

  int k ;
  for (k = 1; k < n ; k++) {
    if (a[k-1] > a[k])
      return 0;

      return 1;
  }
}

int max_el(const int *a, int n)
{
  assert(n >= 1);

  int result = 0, i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (a[i] > result)
      result = a[i];
  return result;
}

#ifdef UNIT_TESTS
#include <stdio.h>


#define COUNT(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

void test_is_sorted(const char *tag, const int *a, int n, int expected_rv);
void test_max_el(const char *tag, const int *a, int n, int expected_rv);

int main(void)
{
  int test_01[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
  int test_02[] = { 10, 10, 10, 10 };
  int test_03[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 35 };
  int test_04[] = { 10, 20, 30, 25, 40 };
  int test_05[] = { 10, 5, 15, 25 };
  test_is_sorted("test_01", test_01, COUNT(test_01), 1);
  test_is_sorted("test_02", test_02, COUNT(test_02), 1);
  test_is_sorted("test_03", test_03, COUNT(test_03), 0);
  test_is_sorted("test_04", test_04, COUNT(test_04), 0);
  test_is_sorted("test_05", test_05, COUNT(test_05), 0);
  fputc('\n', stdout);

  int test_06[] = { 100, 1, 2, 3 };
  int test_07[] = { 1, 2, 100, 3 };
  int test_08[] = { 1, 2, 3, 100 };
  int test_09[] = { -1, -2, -3, -4 };
  int test_10[] = { -8, -7, -6, -7, -8 };
  test_max_el("test_06", test_06, COUNT(test_06), 100);
  test_max_el("test_07", test_07, COUNT(test_07), 100);
  test_max_el("test_08", test_08, COUNT(test_08), 100);
  test_max_el("test_09", test_09, COUNT(test_09), -1);
  test_max_el("test_10", test_10, COUNT(test_10), -6);
  fputc('\n', stdout);

  return 0;
}

void test_is_sorted(const char *tag, const int *a, int n, int expected_rv)
{
  printf("Testing is_sorted for case with tag \"%s\":", tag);
  if (expected_rv == is_sorted(a, n))
    printf(" Pass.\n");
  else
    printf(" FAIL!\n");
}

void test_max_el(const char *tag, const int *a, int n, int expected_rv)
{
  printf("Testing max_el for case with tag \"%s\":", tag);
  if (expected_rv == max_el(a, n))
    printf(" Pass.\n");
  else
    printf(" FAIL!\n");
}

#endif // #ifdef UNIT_TESTS
```

but when I test it it doesnt work, what can I change. 
when i use this test   `int test_04[] = { 10, 20, 30, 35, 40 };`
it returns 0. what am i doing wrong?I have added my entire code but the function still shows some defect, idk why it is doing this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to check whether everything is sorted, shouldn't  you check `a[k] <= a[k+1]`? This does not change your problem, but {10, 30, 20} will come out fine if you algorithm works as you intend it, and that is NOT what you want...

Comment: i tried that, still doesnt work properly

Comment: Please do not edit your question and remove everything just because you got an answer. SO likes to preserve questions for future reference, in case someone else encounters the same problem as you in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, when you did that `if (a[0] <= a[k+ 1])`, you just check if all value in the array are greater or equal than the first element of your array. You must check if an element is greater or equal than the previous element and if it's lesser or equal than the next element.

```
int is_sorted(const int *a, int n)
{
   assert (n >= 1);

   int k;
   for (k = 1 ; k < n ; k++) {
      if (a[k-1] > a[k])
        return 0;
   }
   return 1; 
}
```

Instead of use a variable `result`, you can directly return `0` when you know that the array isn't sorted.

Comment: @Missu shouldn't it be a[k-1] <= a[k]?

Comment: You don't need the test `if (n == 1)`.

Comment: @DianaProdan you want to stop when you know that the array is not sorted, i.e. an element in lesser than a previous element.

Comment: with your code, all my test cases show up as true, because i think ur return statement is outside the for loop.

Comment: @ech0 the return statment is outside the `for` loop because you know the array is sorted only after the `for` loop but you know when it isn't sorted during the `for` loop.

Comment: i have edited my code but it still does not work for { 10, 5, 15, 25 }, it shows up as true. any reason why?

Comment: @ech0 Can you show up your test code ? For me, it say false with the 3 answers given and with `int a[] = { 10, 5, 15, 25 };`

Comment: pass, pass, fail,fail,pass

Comment: @ech0 That's really weird because with your code (and one of the 3 answers), my output is only `Pass`x5

Comment: also do you know whats wrong with my max_el function, its supposed to return the largest element in the array but it doesnt.

Comment: @ech0 And you have compiled it again ? Because that's the output I get with your code (without one of the answers). Otherwise, I have no idea. With `max_el`you did `int result = 0;`and `0` is greater than all other negative values. Try with `int result = a[0];`

Comment: @ech0 yes, the code you've edited above is false, you need to use one of the 3 answers, choose wich one you're most understanding. In your code you return 1 before the end of `for`loop.

Comment: @ech0 and that's what you want, this means that all tests have been taken correctly.

Comment: hi, could you help me one last time. I want to make a function as I put edited in my question. How would I do that, thanks so much.

Comment: @ech0 Take a look on the comment above written by Lundin. If you want to ask another question, create a new topic. But actually your question isn't correct for stackoverflow, you must put some effort and try to answer it by yourself. If what you've done doesn't work, ask your question. Take a look on [how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: okay, thank you. Im new to this site so I dont know the rules. Wont happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Without added local variables

```
int is_sorted(const int *a, int n) {
   assert (n >= 1);

   while (--n)
      if (a[n] < a[n-1])
         return 0;
   return 1; 
}
```

Comment: this does not work with my code, as it shows up 1 for all my test cases

Comment: Ensure to replace `is_sorted` with my func to test it. Then, of course 09 and 10 fail, not due to my `is_sorted` (that works) but because `max_el` initializes the max at 0, so when all elements are negative, it gives 0 instead of max [ neg values ] . Use `INT_MIN` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
int is_sorted(const int *a, int n)
{
  assert (n >= 1);

  if (n == 1)
    return 1;

  int k, result=1;
  for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
    if (a[k] > a[k+ 1])
     {
         result = 0;
         break;
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What does your answer have that the 8 min older answer does not have? (besides an unnecessary local variable)

Comment: same thing . But I saw that when my page reload after my submission. @ringo

Comment: with your code all my statements show up as true. when they r not supposed to

Comment: int test_04[] = { 10, 5, 30, 35, 40 }; for this input . What will be your output? @ech0

Comment: try with my code

`int is_sorted(const int *a, int n)
{


   int k;
   for (k = 1 ; k < n ; k++) {
      if (a[k-1] > a[k])
        return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int test_04[] = { 10, 5, 30, 35, 40 };
    int a=is_sorted(test_04,5);
    printf("%d\n",a);
}`